# PYQT5 Kill or Terminate QThreads

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

When I press pushbutton, thread1 is starting, when I press the pushbutton_2, I want to kill thread1 but althouht I placed "terminate()" for pushbutton_2(Stop button), I can not kill the thread. It caused stop the run function but not kill totaly. 
I guess it's not possible to perform it while using "terminate". How can I perform it?

class thread1(QThread)

```
zaman1=pyqtSignal(int)


def run(self):


    i1=0


    while True:

        i1+=1


        time.sleep(1)



        self.zaman1.emit(i1)

 class Ui_MainWindow(object):
```

Pyt5 codes.....

```
   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):


    self.zaman_thread=thread1()




    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start1)
    self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.stop)



def start1(self):


    self.zaman_thread.zaman1.connect(self.zaman1_result)
    self.zaman_thread.start()



def zaman1_result(self,val):


    self.progressBar.setValue(val)



def stop(self):

    self.zaman_thread.terminate()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

```
ex.setupUi(w)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135444/how-to-kill-a-running-thread)

Comment: Posting only the relevant code and formatting it so that it's easy to read is more likely to get you answers.

Comment: ok, thanks for feedback, adjusted.